# MembershipUser.ResetPassword throw not valid Base-64 Exception

Tags: asp.net, passwords, asp.net-membership

I am getting the following error

[image]

Every time I try and reset a particular users password.

There is only one user I have the problem with and I am using the inbuilt membership provider, so nothing custom.

I have spent a lot of time googling but have found noone else with this problem. I am not sure what to try as it's the inbuilt stuff that is throwing the error.

Any help?

Comment: Why would asp membership generate something invalid?

Comment: As I am not able to fix this I have copied the salt and encrypted password from another user in the Database which is working for me. But I need to find out why it happened and how to stop it doing it again.

Comment: Well, i've never heard of it happening, so either it was a freak accident in which it probably won't happen again, someone was playing in the database and accidentally entered a weird character (which again is unlikely to ever happen again), or you have some rogue code that is updating data in the membership tables (which very well could happen again).

Comment: I shall keep my fingers crossed then. Definitely no rogue code as nothing is touching the membership tables other than the asp.net built in stuff. So far so good! Do you wan to stick it as an answer so at least I can mark an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the users password may contain a unicode character that is not tolerated by the Base-64 encoding. Or, the users Salt contains a non-base-64 compatible salt value.